# Find $b$ such that $0 \le b < 101$ and $2^{987654321} \equiv b \pmod {101}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the unique integer $b$ with $0 \le b < 101$ satisfying $2^{987654321} \equiv b \pmod {101}$.

I am having trouble just starting this problem. This is a home work problem that is going to be on my test and I just can not think of what to do.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $101$ is prime.  Use Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: ..and to simplify the tedious calculations after having applied FLT, one can use $2^{10}=1010+14$.